# Add the cart totals in a the first multistep checkout tab

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

Is there a way to put the Cart Totals as it is in the http://www.ved24.no/cart page for **homepage** http://www.ved24.no/ **under the first "Varer" tab**?

I’m using the WooCommerce Checkout Page Builder For Visual Composer for the multistep woo checkout but it doesn’t populate the:

```
<div class=”cart-collaterals”></div>
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
global $woocommerce;

$cart_totals = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();
```

Then you can use `$cart_totals` the way you want to.

Comment: I need the whole "Cart Totals" section, not only the total price. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry a bit late.. But can't you just look at how the cart is being build inside the cart.php template? You could reproduce the template within a custom shortcode and then you're able to use that shortcode wherever you wish right?